# Input not supported on 75Hz monitor

Tags: nvidia, gnome-shell, login-screen

After getting this new monitor, I have always had display issues with it. This isn’t is just normal Ubuntu, I’ve had issues with every flavor and linux distrobution. For some reason, displaying anything over 60Hz on a 75Hz monitor shows the box “Input not supported.” (The resolution for this monitor is 1920x1080, connected via HDMI)

After connecting a second monitor with refresh rate of 60Hz and a resolution of 1680x1050 works fine.

I am also running Ubuntu on an NVIDIA RTX 3060 with nvidia-driver-525 installed.

Is there a way to force the login screen to stay at 60Hz so I can actually see what I am doing?

Comment: The fact it is happening in more then just Ubuntu says it is a hardware issue.

Comment: It works with no issues on windows 11, but with Linux I have the most problems with